# Google Sheets script does not fully complete on time trigger

Tags: javascript, events, time, triggers, google-sheets

Modified script .. works when run manually, setvalue(date) does not work when run on time trigger. Needs another tweak ... ideas please?

```
function getData() {
  var queryString = Math.random();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('spreadsheet URL');
  var cellFunction = '=IMPORTHTML("stats URL' + queryString + '","table",1)';

  var timezone = "GMT+1";
  var timestamp_format = "EEE, MMM d '@' HH:mm"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);

  Logger.log(ss.getName());

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AH1').setValue(date);

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AF1').setValue(cellFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "ActiveSheet" when running on time trigger, hence it becomes undefined, use one of these methods from SpreadsheetApp to retrive the spreadsheet:

`open(file)`
Spreadsheet Opens the spreadsheet that corresponds to the given

`openById(id)`
Spreadsheet Opens the spreadsheet with the given ID.

`openByUrl(url)`
Spreadsheet Opens the spreadsheet with the given url.

and after it get the sheet with one of the following methods:

`getSheetByName(name)` Returns a sheet with the given name.

`getSheets()[ indexOfTheSheet ]` Returns a sheet with the given 0 based index

Comment: @RichardFoley Show how you've updated the script, here's working just fine.

Comment: You didn't understand my answer, replace ` SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` with `ss.getSheets[0]`.

Comment: updated script above, added 'var ss .... ' and 'logger.log ...' to open sheet as suggested in initial answer. Works manually but not on time trigger event every hour

Comment: True, missed the answer, new to scripts but will remember all my lessons .... thank you will edit and try again.